# Moving of Screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to have a layout (kind doesn't matter) that ia acctual size will be bigger from the real size of the screen multiplies by 5. I have created a surfesview which takes the canvas and draws what I want, but how can I move the screen by touch so I will be able to see every part of the screen? How can I be able to know what view haas been clicked (I want something will happen onClick)?

Comment: How about a ScrollView containing a LinearLayout (or other View) that is 5x the size of your screen. On this LinearLayout (or views inside the LinearLayout) you can simply set an onClickListener. Any reason why you can't use ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would want to use a `OnTouchListener` or  the `View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` to detect touches and act appropriately:

For example:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Perform click operation
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Move to another area based on the event
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or inside your class:

```
int downX = -1;
int downY = -1;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    // You may need the x/y location
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    // put your code in here to handle the event
    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = x;
            downY = y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            downX = -1;
            downY = -1;
            // decide what to do here about movement
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int deltaX = x - downX;
            int deltaY = y - downY;
            // This is one way of doing it, it might not be exactly what you want, but you can start from her
            setTranslationX(getTranslationX() + deltaX);
            setTranslationY(getTranslationY() + deltaY);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: OK. Still, I knew about the on touch listener but how can I make the movement itself?

Comment: Added some code to translate the view (didn't test it though, so you probably have to tweak it).